# Does uniformly bounded and pointwise convergence implies $T_n \to T$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T_n:X\to X$ and $T:X\to X$ be an sequence of bounded linear operator between Banach space.

Assume $T_n(x) \to T(x)$ in $X$ and $\|T_n\| \le 1$.Does the following statement holds?

$$\|T_n-T\|\to 0$$

First by definition we need to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{\|x\|\le 1}\|(T_n-T)x\| = 0$$

If we can commute $\sup$ and $\lim $ the result will holds.I suspect this statement does not holds in general,but I have no idea how to find the counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and let
$$
T_nx=(\overbrace{0,\ldots,0}^{n\ \text{times}},x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots).
$$
Let $T=0$. Then $\|T_n\|=1$ for all $n$, and $T_nx\to Tx$ for all $x$. But $\|T_n-T\|=1$ for all $n$.